# Passing json string from Spring controller to jsp with ModelMap

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to pass a preformed JSON string from a Spring MVC controller method using the ModelMap.addAttribute or put method. I have some data that needs to be loaded when the page renders. I do not want to send a Java object list and then have to unpack it with Javascript into JSON. The problem is that ModelMap.addAttribute or ModelMap.put seems to convert the JSON string back into the Java objects.

When I inspect the added attribute in the JSP I get things like:

```
[foos.web.FOOSController$foosDataHolder@63eef378,foos.web.FOOSController$foosDataHolder@5f395275]
```

In controller:

```
model.put("foosData", jsonFoosString);  // can I just pass a string here?
```

In JSP:

```
var foosData = "${foosData}";
```

Then the JSON parser in the browser cannot parse `foos.web.FOOSController$foosDataHolder@63eef378` and says that `'@'` is an invalid character, which it is.

Thanks for any suggestions for this Spring MVC novice.
I know that I could do an ajax method and get the JSON string back, or unpack an object array in the JSP, but I want this to be fast.

Comment: No, Spring doesn't transform JSON strings to JSON. Your code has a bug, but you didn't post any of it, so...

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely pass a string, but you're not--you're passing a `foosDataHolder` object instead and rendering its default `toString()`.